# Socket IO not working on other machine

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have simple socket io code

```
-- Server

var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});


-- Client

<script src="http://192.168.1.100:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.100:8080');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

there is no problem if the client script run on the server machine , but in other machine rather than server there is no problem in getting socket io javascript file , the client send request to server and I can see that the request received by server , but the client do not receive anything and it try to switch transport after 20 sec , none of them work. But as soon as I close server , the client receive the message that sent from server before ...

I use ubunto 12.04 LTS and Google chrome 28 , please help me through this problem

Comment: i might be wrong but it doesn't seem the HTTP server to actually server a response to a request, and beyond that the IP of the server (if we are referring to the same physical machine) it should not be that..

Comment: where is wrong with my code ?